# Strange java.lang.ClassCastException when using [] call

Tags: java, reflection, libgdx, kotlin

I'm using LibDGX library for my game. And i faced common exception `ClassCastException`, but it occurs in strange case.

I'm using [Animation](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjosLKj6ubXAhXGCJoKHQ4RBo0QFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Flibgdx.badlogicgames.com%2Fnightlies%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fbadlogic%2Fgdx%2Fgraphics%2Fg2d%2FAnimation.html&usg=AOvVaw1X84E6QtOoKNhHovt_jweG) class from LibGDX library.

I'm getting error on this line **only if i am using `[]` operation.**

```
val tex = animation.keyFrames[0]
```

If i change it to `get()` **error disappears**.

```
tex = animation.keyFrames.get(0)
```

Here is full method. I simplified example.

```
override fun create() {


    val frames = Array<TextureRegion>()
    frames.add(TextureRegion(Texture("badlogic.jpg")))

    val animation = Animation(frames)

    val tex1 = animation.keyFrames.get(0)  // Compiles

    val tex = animation.keyFrames[0]  // error - [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;


}
```

Strange, isn't it?

Here is Animation class that i used to minimise other error reasons. It is the same as in LibGDX api.

```
    public class Animation<T> {

    T[] keyFrames;
    private float frameDuration;


    public Animation (float frameDuration, Array<? extends T> keyFrames) {
        this.frameDuration = frameDuration;

        Class arrayType = keyFrames.items.getClass().getComponentType();
        T[] frames = (T[]) ArrayReflection.newInstance(arrayType, keyFrames.size);
        for (int i = 0, n = keyFrames.size; i < n; i++) {
            frames[i] = keyFrames.get(i);
        }

        setKeyFrames(frames);
    }

    protected void setKeyFrames (T... keyFrames) {
        this.keyFrames = keyFrames;
    }
}
```

I also noticed that error **disappears** if i use `Array.with` construction instead of creating `Array<TextureRegion>` I mean LibGDX [Array](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html) not from Kotlin.

```
val animation = Animation(Array.with(TextureRegion(Texture("badlogic.jpg"))))
```

Could you tell me the reason why this occurs or it is possible a bug?

Comment: This isn't the same `Animation` class, [`Animation`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) doesn't have this constructor

Comment: @1blustone Ok, now better? But it doesn't make sense... I tried to make it more readable. Error occurs anyway.

Comment: ah, it makes sense now. You're looking at the current source, which is not in any release yet. This bug seems to be fixed and should be in the next release, see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: In older versions of libGDX, `Animation` does not use `Array`'s reflection capabilities. If it **had**, you wouldn't have this error, because the array would be of the correct type! It should be in libGDX in version 1.9.7. Note: you must specify the `Class` of the `Array` when creating it.

This was fixed recently in [#4476](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4476).
However, the following "bug" with `get` and `[]` resulting in different bytecode for an array may still be worth reporting/inquiring about.

---

This is interesting!

Decompiling

```
val tex1 = animation.keyFrames.get(0)
```

gives

```
ALOAD 2
INVOKEVIRTUAL com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.getKeyFrames ()[Ljava/lang/Object;
ICONST_0
AALOAD
CHECKCAST com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion
ASTORE 3
```

while decompiling

```
val tex = animation.keyFrames[0]
```

gives

```
ALOAD 2
INVOKEVIRTUAL com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.getKeyFrames ()[Ljava/lang/Object;
CHECKCAST [Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion;
ICONST_0
AALOAD
ASTORE 4
```

It is important to note that the type of `keyFrames` is `T[]`, so it cannot possibly have a custom `get` method (assuming no extensions exist.)

It seems that although [the two *should* be equal](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed) (`[]` invokes `operator fun get`), they are not!

The only difference I can see is that the `get` variant checks the type (`CHECKCAST`) after retrieving it via `AALOAD`, while the `[]` variant attempts to check that the type of the array is `T[]` *immediately* after retrieving the array.

However, because `frames` is declared in `Animation`'s constructor:

```
public Animation (float frameDuration, Array<? extends T> keyFrames) {
    this.frameDuration = frameDuration;
    T[] frames = (T[]) new Object[keyFrames.size];
    for (int i = 0, n = keyFrames.size; i < n; i++) {
        frames[i] = keyFrames.get(i);
    }
    setKeyFrames(frames);
}
```

as

```
T[] frames = (T[]) new Object[keyFrames.size];
```

**the actual type of the array is `Object[]`**! So this cast to `TextureRegion[]` fails.

To me, this seems like a libGDX bug.

---

I am able to very easily reproduce this with a simple class in Java:

```
public class JavaObjWithArray<T> {

    private T[] items;

    public JavaObjWithArray(T[] items) {
        this.items = (T[]) new Object[items.length];
        System.arraycopy(items, 0, this.items, 0, items.length);
    }

    public T[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val obj = JavaObjWithArray(arrayOf("a", "b"))

    val one = obj.items.get(0)
    val two = obj.items[0]
}
```

This will also throw a `ClassCastException` on the line with `[]`! Additionally, the bytecode has the same difference.

---

The problem really arises with the lack of generic arrays in Java (and Kotlin). There are two main solutions for this in Java:

- Store an `Object[]` and cast the values upon `get`
- Store an `Object[]`, but cast it to `T[]`

This is a problem - because the actual type of the array *is* `Object[]`. As a consequence, these "generic" arrays *should not be exposed!* I can understand why libGDX does so, namely, to improve performance and remove the small overhead of method calls, but this is definitely not safe.

---

The fact that `get` and `[]` differ *may* be a bug, though. Perhaps looking into this or filing a bug report may help.

---

[Java bytecode instruction list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. It helped really. This question harassed me for a long time. So now we finally decided that this is Kotlin bug? I'il create an issue then.

Comment: @icarumbas The part with `[]` and `get`, it seems like it. Furthermore the documentation states that `[]` and `operator get` should have the same effect. The IntelliJ documentation for `[]` even leads to `get`.

Comment: The specific `ClassCastException` you get here is not a Kotlin bug though, because [it is possible to get this exception even when using libGDX with Java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4476).