# Kotlin Index Operator [0] vs get(0)

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

when my code looks like

```
myList.get(0)
```

Intellij suggest me to replace it with

```
myList.get()[0]
```

what's the advantage ?

[image]

**Update** ... sorry for asking too fast
code was actually

```
myList.get().get(0)
```

myList was holding an **optional** and it all make senses now

Comment: What is myList?

Comment: It's not suggesting `get()[0]`. That shouldn't compile. It's suggesting `myList[0]`. I've also tested that IntelliJ's quick-fix replaces it with that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can replace `myList.get(0)` with `myList[0]`. It’s compiled down to basically the same, but the index operator is more intuitive and recommended as per IntelliJ itself for instance. You can replace `get` calls since `get` is defined as an `operator`, which can, [by convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html), be replaced with the index operator.

Comment: Well, strangely, [it isn't _exactly_ the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579524/strange-java-lang-classcastexception-when-using-call/47579973#47579973) (at least for arrays).